# How can I get the temp folder of a machine running maven?

Tags: java, linux, windows, maven, pom.xml

I'd like to save some unpacked files into the temp folder of a machine.

**Question**: How can I get the temp folder using maven?

**Question**: Will it work on both linux and windows environments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maven [supports](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html), as part of the default properties, any [Java System property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()), hence you can use the following property:

> **`java.io.tmpdir`**  Default temp file path

As example:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.10</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>unpack</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>unpack</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <!-- further conf here -->
           <outputDirectory>${java.io.tmpdir}/libs</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note the `outputDirectory` element and its value.

---

As a further note, also note that the `target` folder of the Maven build is also meant to host temporary files, so you should also consider to use it for such a purpose.

---

> Will it work on both linux and windows environments?

Yes, since it is Java property, it is supposed to be OS independent.

Answer (score 5):

use the java environment tmp dir - `java.io.tmpdir`
you can access it from maven via `${java.io.tmpdir}` without having to predefine it.

you can also customize it on a specific run by running:

```
mvn clean install -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/where/ever
```